# Logic behind complex lines

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to draw a line from point A to point B. However the lines itself should be intelligent in the sense that if point B is `exactly` below point A a straight line should get drawn. But if the point B is below A and little far horizontally from A then a line should get drawn in right angled manner. I hope you are getting me. If you may have used any UML tool like edraw Max or any other you may have seen these types of lines. Any idea how can we achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some code:

```
void connectPoints(Point a, Point b)
{
    Point middlePoint1(a.x, (a.y + b.y)/2);
    Point middlePoint2(b.x, (a.y + b.y)/2);
    drawLine(a, middlePoint1);
    drawLine(middlePoint1, middlePoint2);
    drawLine(middlePoint2, b);
}
```

To clarify, the asker actually wants 3-segment axis-aligned lines that look like most connections here:
[image: style]

Comment: You are right. This is the exact desired behavior. Let me what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with straightforward approach?

```
// pA, pB - points
DrawLine(pA.X, pA.Y, pA.X, pB.Y); // vertical line from A point down/up to B
DrawLine(pA.X, pB.Y, pB.X, pB.Y); // horizontal line to B
```

Comment: +1 The basic idea is right on.   A more complicated topic is, how does OP handle diagrams in which multiple lines being drawn might collide?  For these orthogonal lines, there are actaully two lines he could draw: e.g, down and right, vs. right and down. Now he has 1000 of these to draw, giving him a space of 2^1000 possible configurations.   Which one does he draw to minimize line overlaps? Which one does he draw to avoid lines with corner point collisions?  The hard problem is this layout problem.

Comment: @Ira, it's hard to answer unasked question. I agree that generally this problem is complicated, but this particular question have not that many details, so I assumed that easiest way may be enough here. Other solutions may be overengineered since we don't know what he really needs.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean by right angled intelligence? pseudo ensue...

```
Point pA(x,y);
Point pB(x,y);
if abs(pB.X-pA.X) < abs(pB.Y-pA.Y) // Going vertically or horizontal?
{
    DrawLine(pA.X, pA.Y, pA.X, pB.Y); //Long vertical
    DrawLine(pA.X, pB.Y, pB.X, pB.Y); //Short horizontal
}
else
{
    DrawLine(pA.X, pA.Y, pB.X, pA.Y); //Long horizontal
    DrawLine(pB.X, pA.Y, pB.X, pB.Y); //Short vertical
}
```

or for the crooked line (off the top of my head):

```
Point pA=(x,y);
Point pB=(x,y)
if abs(pB.X-pA.X) < abs(pB.Y-pA.Y) // Going vertically or horizontal?
{
    Point pHalfwayY = (pB.Y-pA.Y)/2 + pB.Y
    DrawLine(pA.X, pA.Y, pA.X, pHalfwayY ); //Long vertical 1st half
    DrawLine(pA.X, pHalfwayY , pB.X, pHalfwayY ); //Short horizontal
    DrawLine(pA.X, pHalfwayY , pA.X, pB.Y); //Long vertical 2nd half
}
else
{
    Point pHalfwayX = (pB.X-pA.X)/2 + pB.Y
    DrawLine(pA.X, pA.Y,pHalfwayX , pA.Y); //Long horizontal 1st Half
    DrawLine(pHalfwayX , pA.Y, pHalfwayX , pB.Y); // Short Vertical
    DrawLine(pHalfwayX , pA.Y, pA.X, pB.Y); //Long horizontal 2nd half
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics libraries like **GDI+** will handle that for you, and it will draw the line according to its starting and ending points.

If you want to handle this your self, you have to work with triangular math to determine the rotation angle of your line.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the solution he needs. I believe he actually wants to connect to points with straight (horizontal/vertical) lines only. Though description is not very clear.

Comment: @Snowbear : You are right. I want to draw horizontal and vertical lines only. No cross lines.